# Upload all files from a directory using python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have 200+ pdf files in a directory, and I want to upload all files in one click using Python script (No Browse Button) into a database.

At first I tried to upload a single file but it didn't work:

```
import pymysql
path = r'C:\Users\Rishabh\Desktop\Source Folder\000098745 (10).pdf'
connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", 
database="avantha")
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO testing(FILE) VALUES('"+path+"')"
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I've also attached the structure of table and result after running above code.[Structure Of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJLMi.jpg)
[Table After Running Above Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzbAv.jpg)

I've googled but I found only PHP codes. Please help...

Thanks

Comment: You want to upload data of all files in the same table in MySQL?

Comment: No, I want to upload all PDF files in the same table, not the data of file. Like this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfobCv4YBdk) but using only python (without any GUI or Browse button) @MayankPorwal